# How to make unit test with exception using JUnit5?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have `UserService` and there GET method which returns the object found by id. Let's say:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

I made simple test if the user is found:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class  UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void whenGivenId_shouldReturnUser_ifFound() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(89L);

        when(userRepository.findById(user.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));

        User expected = userService.getUserById(user.getId());

        assertThat(expected).isSameAs(user);
        verify(userRepository).findById(user.getId());
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a method, let's say: `public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenUserDoesntExist()`. How to make it in JUnit5? In JUnit4 I would make something like this:

```
    @Test(expected = UserNotFoundException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenUserDoesntExist() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(89L);
        user.setName("Test Name");

        given(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).willReturn(Optional.ofNullable(null));
        userService.getUserById(user.getId());
    }
```

Since this `@Test(expected = UserNotFoundException.class)` is outdated in JUnit5, I can't find anywhere what's the way in handling exception like this one in JUnit5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
Assertions.assertThrows(UserNotFoundException.class, () -> {
    userService.getUserById(1234);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Assertions.assertThrows().
The assertThrows() method asserts that execution of the supplied executable block throws an exception of the expected type. It takes the following parameters.

```
static <T extends Throwable>T assertThrows(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable)

static <T extends Throwable>T assertThrows(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable, String message)

static <T extends Throwable>T assertThrows(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable, Supplier<String> messageSupplier)
```